# Fixing left and right margin in bootstrap row inside card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am not able to customize left and right margin for bootstrap row inside card. Here are my css code and some screenshots.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card shadow bg-white pt-1 pb-1 rounded">
                    <div class="row" id="xyz">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <p><b>1,933</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <p><b>&#8377;100</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4" style="white-space:nowrap">
                            <p><b>&#8377;4,000</b></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="mx-auto d-block card-img" src="../../assets/images/note_9_pro_max1.jpg" alt="note-pro-max" style="width: 50px; height: 100px;">
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-6" style="white-space:nowrap">
                            <p><b>&#8377;1,000</b></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Bootstrap Card]

[image: Row inside card]

Answer (score 0):

Add

pl-1 and pr-1 in card div and try...

```
  <div class="card shadow bg-white pt-1 pb-1 pl-1 pr-1 rounded">
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u813z9xo/)**

Comment: I already tried giving padding to card or margin to row. But its not working. Even in your case, i ran it and removing padding making no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I found a working solution. You can set the "width" of the card to percentages.

```
<div class="card shadow bg-white pt-1 pb-1 rounded" style="width: 95% !important">
```